# How can I make my program utilize tab completion?

Tags: python, shell, command-line-interface, tab-completion

I've noticed that some programs (e.g. hg) allow the user to tab-complete specific parts of the command. For example, if, in an hg repository working directory, I type:

`hg qpush --move b8<TAB>`

It will try to complete the command with any mercurial patches in my patch queue that start with "b8".

What I'd like to do is imitate this behavior in my program. That is, I have a series of commands that depend on files within a certain directory, and I'd like to be able to provide tab completion in the shell. Is there an API for providing this on Ubuntu Linux (preferably using python, as that's what my script is written in)?

Comment: Maybe something like this:  http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html

Comment: As @mgilson response implies, the shell has to be configured in order to provide autocompletion for your program, not the other way round.

Answer (score 11):

To do this, you need to write tab-completion modules for your shell. The default shell in most Linux distributions is `bash`, so you should write a completion script (typically a shell script). Once you've written your script, add it to `/etc/bash_completion.d/`. This should be distributed with your program (for Linux distributions, included in the package).

Debian Administration has [a guide for writing your completion scripts](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2). For using completion on a Mac, see https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion.

For examples of completion files, take a look at the [`bash-completion` project from Debian](http://alioth.debian.org/projects/bash-completion/) (also [on Github](https://github.com/GArik/bash-completion)). See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/an-easy-bash-completion-tutorial.

If you use `zsh`, [hack.augusto linked to the documentation for writing completions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14885791/319931).

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#module-readline) module is for.

Actually, readline is a common C library so it has bindings in many languages. And I can say, I've had tons of fun with it.

Enjoy B)

Comment: I think the asker wants to know how to get the *shell* to autocomplete subcommands for his program, not how to use autocompletion *within* the program.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but actually, I'm writing a program in Python that I want to _ship_ with automatic tab completion (for shells that support it).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `zsh` shell, it has a great completion system with support for tons of applications.

The completion system is written with the shell language, but if you really want to use python you can run the interpreter from inside your completion function. The down side it that if you want to write completion for your own software, you will need to do some reading ([user manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System) and the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshcompsys) for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source of the 'cmd' module in the Python library. It supports command completion.